How to run Github Action job only if all previous jobs are successful?
I try to setup yml file on Github Action. The task is to run the 4th job ONLY if all 3 other jobs are successful.
name: Test and Build
on:
  push:

jobs:
  run-debug-tests:
    name: Unit tests
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    continue-on-error: true


  run-ui-tests:
    name: Android Tests
    runs-on: macos-latest
    continue-on-error: true


  lint:
    name: Lint check
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    continue-on-error: true


  build_job:
   name: Building the APK
   runs-on: ubuntu-latest
   needs: [run-debug-tests, run-ui-tests, lint]

I tried to apply some conditions for the 4th job tbut didn't help:
if: run-debug-tests.result == 'success' && run-ui-tests.result == 'success' && lint.result == 'success'


Right now the 4th job runs when any of the jobs fail.
Could you please help me?

Are there any errors being printed? What is actually happening when you try to trigger the action? Is the 4th job running when one of the three others fails, or is the 4th job not running when the other three succeed?

Right now the 4th job runs when any of the other jobs fail.

Why did you use continue-on-error: true ? so that the workflow doesn't stop running the 3 jobs if one of the jobs fails, maybe?

In any case, you might want to remove continue-on-error: true from your workflow.yml…

Unfortunately, removing continue-on-error: true from all jobs didn't help

I observed you commented above that:
"Unfortunately, removing continue-on-error: true from all jobs didn't help"
Which was strange as the behavior of continue-on-error: true at the job level is the following one:

Job Status: Even if a step within the job fails, the job will not be marked as failed. Instead, the job will be marked as "success" (green checkmark) in the GitHub Actions UI, but the failure will still be logged in the job's output.
Step Status: The individual step that failed will still be marked as failed (red cross), but the overall job will not fail.

So I made a test to check the behavior:

Workflow 1: The same workflow as you shared with continue-on-error: true enabled for each job.

The output is the same as you shared: 

Workflow 2: The same workflow as you shared, REMOVING continue-on-error: true for each job.

In that case, the last job indeed didn't run as the one failing broke the pipeline:

Conclusion:
Disabling continue-on-error: true for the 3 initial jobs should indeed resolve your issue, as ErickMD stated in the comments as well. Except if there are some more details in your workflow configs you didn't share in your question.

Also, note that to check the previous job statuses in the last job, you would need to use the following syntax in you if condition: ${{ needs.<job-name>.result == 'success' }}.
  build_job:
   name: Building the APK
   runs-on: ubuntu-latest
   needs: [run-debug-tests, run-ui-tests, lint]
   if: ${{ needs.run-debug-tests.result == 'success' && needs.run-ui-tests.result == 'success' && needs.lint.result == 'success' }}
   steps:
     ...

